# Android "Trying to pause when pause is already pending "

Tags: android, android-intent

I've been getting this exception for some time.  I have not noticed it preventing any functionality, but I'd prefer not to deploy with this going on in the background, in case it leads to bigger problems.  Does anyone have any clue what it means?

From the Android log:

```
09-06 08:14:45.562: I/ActivityManager(455): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.foo.main/.ui.config.InitialActivity} from pid 3435
09-06 08:14:45.582: I/ActivityManager(455): Start proc org.foo.main for activity org.foo.main/.ui.config.InitialActivity: pid=3447 uid=10091 gids={50091, 1028, 1015, 3003}
09-06 08:14:45.727: I/ActivityManager(455): START u0 {flg=0x4000000 cmp=org.foo.main/.ui.LoginActivity} from pid 3447
09-06 08:14:45.757: E/ActivityManager(455): Trying to pause when pause is already pending for ActivityRecord{41e1de20 u0 org.foo.main/.ui.LoginActivity t6}
09-06 08:14:45.757: E/ActivityManager(455): java.lang.RuntimeException: here
09-06 08:14:45.757: E/ActivityManager(455):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:726)
09-06 08:14:45.757: E/ActivityManager(455):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.checkReadyForSleepLocked(ActivityStack.java:657)
09-06 08:14:45.757: E/ActivityManager(455):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkReadyForSleepLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2197)
09-06 08:14:45.757: E/ActivityManager(455):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:1600)
09-06 08:14:45.757: E/ActivityManager(455):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeTopActivitiesLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2022)
09-06 08:14:45.757: E/ActivityManager(455):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.completePauseLocked(ActivityStack.java:921)
09-06 08:14:45.757: E/ActivityManager(455):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityPausedLocked(ActivityStack.java:820)
09-06 08:14:45.757: E/ActivityManager(455):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityPaused(ActivityManagerService.java:5234)
09-06 08:14:45.757: E/ActivityManager(455):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:426)
09-06 08:14:45.757: E/ActivityManager(455):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2071)
09-06 08:14:45.757: E/ActivityManager(455):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
09-06 08:14:45.757: E/ActivityManager(455):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Here is the only significant piece of code in InitialActivity, which just reroutes to the LoginActivity if the app has been initialized and registered:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ConfigInfoManager configInfoManager = new ConfigInfoManager(this);      
    switch(configInfoManager.getInitState()) {
            ...
    case REGISTERED:
        new ServiceManager(this).schedulePingRepeating();
        Actions.loginScreen(this);
        break;
    }
}

public static void loginScreen(Activity context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

I assume it is not relevant, but at random places in the app, this piece of code is used to go back to the login screen:

```
public static void logout(Activity context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, InitialActivity.class);
    intent = Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(intent.getComponent());
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

And finally, here are the relevant parts from the manifest:

> ```
>      <activity
>         android:name=".ui.config.InitialActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:noHistory="true"
>         android:screenOrientation="landscape"
>         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity
>         android:name=".ui.LoginActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_login_name"
>         android:screenOrientation="landscape"
>         android:theme="@style/LoginTheme"
>         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
>     </activity>
> ```